# compiling with code coverage in catkin

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone use the "Coverage" option when compiling? I would like to get a profile of my executable, so I compile with 'catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Coverage' and have confirmed that the code runs noticeably slower (although this may also be due to more optimization being disabled?). I do not know where to recover the code profile information from.

Running Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120906/compiling-with-code-coverage-in-catkin/) by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on 2014-02-03**:
FYI - I ended up using valgrind to profile my code. To profile a single node, it may be easiest to run "valgrind --tool=callgrind ./<name_of_node_executable>" in the directory of your executable rather than using http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not directly familiar with the `Coverage` build type, but if it creates binaries instrumented with gcov (fi) then <del>wouldn't the profiling data be generated upon executing the binary, and in the `cwd`?</del> No.

---

Edit: also, is the `Coverage` build type still supported with catkin? I can only find references to it in rosbuild `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Edit2: according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405454) stack overflow answer, the coverage information ends up in the directory where the object files are, so for CMake / catkin that would probably be in the `build` space of your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on 2014-02-03**:
Thanks, that was a good link. I searched my package high and low for any coverage files, or links from executables to coverage files, and came up with nil. Passing Catkin the Coverage flag makes entire package recompile, but apparently not actually generate coverage info.